# how to initialize an output on verilog (sequential circuit)

Tags: initialization, verilog, test-bench

I'm new to Verilog coding and I have a college project to design a simple elevator system. The code worked perfectly fine on the FPGA but I cannot get the simulation to work. This is my code:

```
module move(
    output reg [1:0] current,
    input [1:0] target,
    input clk,
    input overloadin,
    output reg up,
    output reg down
    );

always@(posedge clk)
if (overloadin==1'b0)
begin
if (target[1:0]>current[1:0])
begin
current[1:0] <= current[1:0] + 1;
up = 1'b1;
down = 1'b0;

end
else if (target[1:0]<current[1:0])
begin
current[1:0] <= current[1:0] - 1;
down = 1'b1;
up = 1'b0;

end
else
begin
up = 1'b0;
down = 1'b0;

end
end
endmodule
```

'current' is declared as wire in the top module. I'm assuming I cannot simulate it because the value of 'current' was not initialized. How can I initialize the value of it without affecting the functionality of the always block?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an 'initial' statement or add a reset signal.

```
initial
   current = 2'b00;
```

or

```
  input reset_n,
  ...
   always @(posedge clk or negedge reset_n)
   begin
      if (!reset_n)
         current <= 2'b00;
      else
      ...
   end
```

I personally prefer the latter but you can find several discussions on the use of initial vs reset in this and the ee forum.

I have not checked the rest of your code because to me it is unreadable due to the lack of indenting.

Answer (score 0):

you are mixing blocking and non-blocking statements together is causing race condition during simulation. I have modified your code.

```
module move(
 output reg [1:0] current,
 input [1:0] target,
 input clk,
 input reset_n,             //Added an additional input
 input overloadin,
 output reg up,
 output reg down
);

always@(posedge clk or negedge reset_n)
begin
 if(!reset_n)               //Active low reset
 begin
   up      <= 1'd0;
   down    <= 1'd0;
   current <= 2'd0;
 end
else if(!overloadin)
begin
 if(target > current)
 begin
  up      <= 1'd1;
  down    <= 1'd0;
  current <= current + 2'd1;
 end
 else if(target < current)
 begin
  up      <= 1'd0;
  down    <= 1'd1;
  current <= current - 2'd1;
 end
else
 begin
  up      <= 1'd0;
  down    <= 1'd0;
 end
  end  end  endmodule
```